# Instance from another instance in Python

Tags: python, c++, class, constructor

In C++, the constructor of a class allows an instance to be constructed from another instance. e.g.

```
C::C(const C & c) {
    bala...;
    cc = c.cc;
}
```

In Python, what is the similar way of doing this? How may I use

```
c1 = C()
c2 = C(c1)
```

?

Comment: There are no compile-time types in Python. Just do `c2 = c1`.

Comment: What is `bala` supposed to be there? And your question is strange; you've written C++ code that takes an instance, and assigns its attributes to another instance, why don't you do the same in Python?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks. I actually wanted to say something more there. It can be also cc = "This is a copy " + c.cc; Something like that. The answer barak gave was a copy of the same instance also. But I really wanted something more than just a copy.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks. Your solution provides a copy of c1, but in C++ there can be more in the constructor, like what I said in reply to Daniel.

Comment: @frankliuao,Is your problem resolved now ? Was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't mention the type while defining a variable in python. For example: if `x=4`, you can always set x to something else, `x="shasha"`. No problem at all.

*Note we can not overload a method in python.*

**Coming back to your question:**

Assuming that you understand the python memory management and the difference between a `reference` and an `actual value`, You may use `deepcopy` feature in python:

```
import copy
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.a=10

x = A()

y= copy.deepcopy(x)

x.a=15

print(y.a)  # prints 10.
```

Note that you can always copy one object into another using `= operator` like `y = x` but it wont actually copy anything. Now both the references y and x will actually be pointing to the same instance. i.e. if you change anything using one, it will automatically be reflected into the other one:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.a=10

x = A()

y = x

x.a=15

print(y.a)  # prints 15.
```

---

You can also create a dummy constructor as mentioned in following example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10

    def dummy_constructor(self):
        temp = A()
        temp.a = (self.a + 20 - 5 )*100/10

        return temp


x=A()

y=x.dummy_constructor()

print(y.a)   #250
print(x.a)   #10
```

Comment: Thanks shasha. It's sort of what I wanted but not exactly. I was looking for something similar to C++, where if I define in the constructor like cc = c.cc (in my original post) or cc = "this is a copy " + c.cc, so you automatically know it's a copy of another instance. Something like that. If you use deepcopy, I'm afraid you have to do this by yourself, such as x=A(), y=copy.deepcopy(x), y.a="copy" + x.a.

Comment: You can not create a copy constructor in python as we do in c++. So you will have to go with some alternative. I have updated my explanation and added an alternative. Will that do good for you ?